# How can I force scripts to finish before leaving the page (in webkit browsers)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, webkit

This already works well in FireFox, IE and Opera, but in Chrome and Safari this is a problem. I have an onClick event function on links that leaves the page. These functions send requests to various tracking services to record the exit link.

I have tested this by removing the `href` attribute in the link. When it's removed, the link is tracked. When the link is active (and leads away from the page) the link is not tracked. This is only the case in Chrome and Safari.

I was hoping there was some non-extreme way of forcing the browser to finish the script before leaving the page. (By extreme I mean f.inst. removing the `href` attribute using javascript and manually redirecting the browser after tracking is complete)

jQuery is already loaded in this project, so it'd be great if it had a solution.

Thanks for any and all advice

Comment: If you remove the href, how is it tracked? You have an "onclick" on the label? Is it a label? Could you post a sample code?

Comment: As I said in the main post: I have a link with an onclick event function. The function simply calls the tracking code from Yahoo! Web Analytics and Google Analytics. It's really as simple as it sounds, so there really is no need for sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google analytics _trackPageView does not offer a callback so you have no easy way to get a success callback, then proceed to your next page. There is a callback though on _trackEvent, and that's triggered each time some GA event occurs. You can try this and listen for it like so (make sure to put your href's back into your links - this depends on that being there, plus you'll get graceful degradation):

```
$(".myLinkClass").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    pageTracker._trackPageview('/outbound/'+link);
    if (pageTracker._trackEvent("Outbound", "URL", link)) {
       window.location = link;
    }
});
```